# Div sorting through multiple checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page there are several Div that hold rating point and also some checkbox. Basically i want based on checkbox selection Div rating will show.i don't know how do that through jquery.
for Example

```
    <div id="ratingbox"> 
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>  
    </div>
    <div id="chkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ratingCheckbox" value="1" onclick="selection()">1
        <input type="checkbox" class="ratingCheckbox" value="2" onclick="selection()">2
        <input type="checkbox" class="ratingCheckbox" value="3" onclick="selection()">3
        <input type="checkbox" class="ratingCheckbox" value="4" onclick="selection()">4
        <input type="checkbox" class="ratingCheckbox" value="5" onclick="selection()">5</div>
```

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/dnyfmhyx/)

if checkbox 1 is checked, span with value 1 will be visible and all others will be hidden, If checkbox 1 and 4 are checked span with value 1 and span with value 4 are only visible and rest are hidden. if no checkbox is checked then all are visible.

Comment: please explain this more **based on checkbox selection Div rating will show**

Comment: Div hold rating value that come from database. like 1 to 5

Comment: You mean if checkbox 1 is checked only the spans containing 1 are visible and so on?

Comment: It might be just me but it is still not clear what the question is. Please be more descriptive in your question and show the community that you have made some efforts to solve the problem and not just left it for others to solve.

Comment: if someone checkbox 1 then only, span show that have value 1.  if any one select checkbox1 and checkbox 2 then it will show, span that have value 1 and 2. so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('.ratingCheckbox').on('click', function(){
    $('span:contains('+this.value+')').toggle();
});
```

And hide the spans by default with this in css `display: none;`

Check the demo here **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/dnyfmhyx/4/**

**Update**

Try something like this

```
var checkbox = $('.ratingCheckbox').on('change', function () {
    var val = checkbox.map(function (index, el) {
        return (el.checked) ? +$(el).val() : undefined;
    }).get(); // this will get the list of checked values in an array like this - [1,4]
    if (val.length > 0) { // if at least one checkbox is checked
        $('span').hide(); // hide all
        $('span').filter(function (index, el) { // this will get all the spans which have value 1 and 4 from the above array
            return $.inArray(+$(el).text(), val) != -1 ? el : undefined; 
        }).show(); // show the ones that are checked
    } else { 
        $('span').show(); // if no checkbox is checked show everything
    }
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/dnyfmhyx/5/**

Comment: @Anjyr: why would that be ?

Comment: because i have to show all rating then sorting operation will implement.

Comment: I don't quite understand what sorting operation you are talking about. Can you please explain that more ?

Comment: if anyone select checkbox 1 then only those span show they have text/value 1. simple i want. i use sorting word for this type of functionality.

Comment: if checkbox 1 is checked, span with value `1` will be visible and all others will be hidden, right ? If checkbox 1 and 4 are checked span with value 1 and span with value 4 are only visible and rest are hidden. Did I understand it right ?

Comment: if no checkbox is checked then all are visible ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76815/discussion-between-anjyr-and-dhiraj-bodicherla).

Answer (score 0):

I give the spans `display: none;` when the corresponding checkbox is check I add `.visible` class to them:

```
#ratingbox > span {
    /* other styles */
    display: none;
}
#ratingbox > span.visible {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

In the jQuery part we just need to get the value of the new changed checkbox and toggle the visible class of corresponding spans (I used `onchange` instead of `onclick`):

```
$('#chkbox > input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#ratingbox > span').each(function() {
        if($(this).text() == val)
            $(this).toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/sn6pf0at/1/)